# Install NUnit with Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, nunit, nunit-3.0, nunittestadapter

I'm trying to create an NUnit C# project. For that purpose, I have installed NUnit 3 Test Adapter from menu *Tools* → *Extensions And Updates*. I then restarted Visual Studio.

But there is still no NUnit project available when trying to create a new project.

How can I get this to work?

Comment: The test adapter just let's you run tests - have you installed the NUnit NuGet packages which actually contain the NUnit assemblies?

Comment: Do you expect there will be a new NUnit project option in "Add New Project" window? If yes, there is no such option, even with proprietary adapter. For NUnit tests, just create new Class Library.

Answer (score 3):

To get this to work, please install the following NuGet packages:

- [NUnit](https://www.nuget.org/packages/nunit/)
- [NUnit3TestAdapter](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NUnit3TestAdapter/)
- [Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk/)

After installation, save the solution and then restart Visual Studio.

Comment: How exactly should they be installed? Can you provide a more operational answer?

Answer (score 1):

Please uninstall the test adapter you installed.

https://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/dhananjay_kumar/archive/2015/07/27/getting-started-with-net-unit-testing-using-nunit.aspx

The proper way now is to install the test adapter NuGet package.